# Ionic 2 loadingController cssClass not working

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2

I want my loadingController wrapper to be shown with a customized css style but the css's rules doesn't apply to the element (the loadingController wrapper).

I have this in my component:

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    let loader = this.loadingController.create({
        spinner: 'bubbles',
        content: 'getting data...',
        cssClass: 'loadingwrapper'
    });
    loader.present().then(() => {
        //some stuff
        ...
        loader.dismiss();
    });
}
```

and this in my css file:

```
.loadingwrapper{
    width: 77% !important;
    height: 15% !important;
    color: black !important;
    font-size: 1.25em !important;
    background-color: aliceblue !important;
    border-radius: 10px !important;
}
```

In spite of doing this (I've even tried whithout "!important"), the changes (none of them) doesn't apply to the loading wrapper and it shows a bit awful.

Comment: Please show more code. "doesn't apply to the element" - what "element"?

Comment: The element is the wrapper (the spinner moving in a white box with a message)

Comment: If Angular2 is involved there can an awful lot of things apply to styling issues. If you don't provide your code it's hard to give a more concrete answer than "there is probably some mistake somewhere in your app" ;-)

Comment: Believe me, that code is enough.

Comment: Perhaps for you to understand the problem, but probably not, otherwise you would be able to solve it. For me definitely not. Perhaps someone else...

Comment: Dear Günter, thanks for helping, but I haven't more relevant code to show. What you see is practically what I have.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you are applying the `css` but if you are applying the `css` in the page component file you going to have a hard time, because the loading controller sits outside the page selector. So if your page component name is `Foobar` and you have a `.scss` file `foobar.scss`

```
page-foobar{
    .loadingwrapper{
        // not going to work
    }
}
```

you can either add it globally to your `app/app.scss` file or ( i think this will work )

```
.md,.ios,.wp{
    page-foobar{
       .loadingwrapper{
        // styles!
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm applying the css in the page component file. I've add what you've told me to my app/app.scss but only with the class selector and now... it works! Thanks a lot

Comment: yeah no worries

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it globally inside the `variables.scss` file.

*Android*

```
$loading-md-border-radius:10px;
```

*ios*

```
$loading-ios-border-radius: 10px
```

*Windows*

```
$loading-wp-border-radius:  10px
```

You can see [**global variable list here**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/loading/LoadingController/#sass-variables).